# Modulus calculation in print function?

Tags: python

What I am missing here?

```
print('i % 100 = %d ' % (i % 100))
```

gives me: `ValueError: unsupported format character ' ' (0x20) at index 7`

```
a = i % 100
print('i % 100 = %d ' % (a))
```

Same error again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape `%` in the format string (using *another* `%`):

```
print('i %% 100 = %d ' % (i % 100))
```

In general, the character after an unescaped `%` is treated as a format specifier, and a space is an invalid specifier, hence the error.

Comment: Ahh so it's problem with that %, I thought it's modulus. Thanks arshajii.